# Android Application Initialization

Tags: android

I have an application that is driven by a configuration XML: various
app properties are loaded at the app start-time by parsing the XML and
initializing static variables of some class. The data read from this
XML drives different Activities of the application. Presently, I have
called the "parsing and the properties-initialization" from the
onCreate() of my Main Activity.

I have a few questions as regards this case/approach:

1. Should I invoke the app initialization method from the Application
   Object or is the current approach correct? What advantages/
   disadvantages do/would we get/have if I choose to invoke it from the
   Application object?
2. Do we really need a static class to store app properties? Or can we have all the properties as a static Collection variable in the application object?
3. Parsing a XML(~200 nodes) at app load time might take some time(not
   sure how long tho); How can I avoid the dreaded ANRs? I am using a
   Pull Parser.

Please help me find answers to these questions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object is used for sharing **non-persistent** state across the application.  I don't think you'll need to use an `Application` class at all.  You can do your initialisation in the `onCreate()` method of the `Activity` that is called first.  To [quote the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm):

> The subclass is optional; most applications won't need one. In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the base Application class.

You don't need to create your own class to store application properties.  This is done for you by [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

You should also have a look at the [`setDefaultValues()` method in the `PreferenceManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues(android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean))
 class as this will set preferences from the data in an XML file.  What's nice about this method is that use the `readAgain` parameter so that the XML is only parsed once - the first time you start up your application - rather than every time.

Answer (score 10):

1. It depends on what you're initializing.  Application's `onCreate()` should be used when you're doing things that need to be done before any part of your app works correctly and only needs to be done once, whereas Activity/Service/etc's `onCreate()` should be used for things that are needed for that component alone and needs to be done multiple times.

   The main concern I have for putting all your initialization into a component is that it will make extending your application more difficult later on.  Suppose you want to make some Activity in your application accessible by outside intents - now you've got to either move the initialization code to Application or you have to duplicate initialization code in the non-launcher Activity.
2. It sounds like you should check out [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), especially [PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)).  The preferences will be stored between sessions and it gives you easy access to simple properties from any Context.
3. Threading.  I find [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to be the easiest way to accomplish this task; there's [a good write-up on it at Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html).  Alternatively, you could fire up a Service to do this in the background while having a foreground Activity inform the user that you're booting up the app.